# Elasticsearch local node client NPE when creating index in java test

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-boot

I am using elasticsearch (v2.3.2/Windows 7) local node to create an index in a java test which is throwing an null pointer exception.

The test code is as follows:

```
CreateIndexResponse response =  esClient.admin().indices().prepareCreate("mytestindex")
       .setSettings(Settings.builder()
               .put("number_of_replicas", 0)
               .put("number_of_shards", 1))
       .execute().actionGet();
```

I have verified esClient is created by spring and is not null. The code to create the client is:

```
@Bean
public Client localElasticsearchClient() {

    Settings settings = Settings.settingsBuilder()
            .put("path.home", "/tmp/elasticsearch")
            .put("path.data", "/tmp/elasticsearch")
            .build();

    return NodeBuilder.nodeBuilder()
            .local(true)
            .settings(settings)
            .build()
            .client();

}
```

The stacktrace is as follows:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.TransportMasterNodeAction$AsyncSingleAction.<init>(TransportMasterNodeAction.java:129)
at org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.TransportMasterNodeAction.doExecute(TransportMasterNodeAction.java:107)
at org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.TransportMasterNodeAction.doExecute(TransportMasterNodeAction.java:51)
at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction.execute(TransportAction.java:137)
at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction.execute(TransportAction.java:85)
at org.elasticsearch.client.node.NodeClient.doExecute(NodeClient.java:58)
```

I saw something [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/18962) about it but there was no info on how to correct it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the answer was *implicitly* given in this [link](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/18962)

I was not calling node.start() method i.e.

```
return NodeBuilder.nodeBuilder()
        .local(true)
        .settings(settings)
        .build()
        .start()
        .client();
```